# how to make an active connection in jftp script?

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

on executing the command
jftp list -port XXX %USER% %PASSWORD% %SOURCE% it goes by default to passive mode which is the default behavior of jftp.
But i need the connection through jftp to be an active connection.

tried with option -a but no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through some documentation found out that the option is -nopasv to run jftp as an active connections.